# How do I delete the left bottom Gmail notifications that I've deleted an email?

Tags: gmail

Every email I delete gets a reminder on the left bottom of screen that I've just deleted it. Is there a setting to make these notifications not appear?

Comment: Are you perhaps asking about the GMail website?

Comment: you referring to this?   https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3exR.png